# Can considering more independent variables lead to higher RMSE?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, model-evaluation, rms

I am running a linear regression analysis with one and two independent variables. In most cases, RMSE is higher when testing the model on a test set considering both independent variables. Although, the R² values increase.

How is it possible that my model becomes more unprecise when I consider more explaining variables?

Comment: did you fit both models on the same data set?

Comment: This might be my mistake. The compared R² derives from the training set and the RMSE from the test set. The right approach would be to claculate the R² also for the test set right?

Comment: Yes you must use the same data set for the comparison to make much meaning!

Answer (score 1):

1. Increased value of $R^2$ does not imply a better model. 
   No matter what variable you add to your model the $R^2$ will increase anyway since the SSE will decrease whenever you add a new variable. For a detailed proof you can refer to [this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/statistics/comments/33bu59/why_does_r2_always_increase_when_adding_new/). That's why it is better to use adjusted $R^2$
2. Even if you use adjusted $R^2$ it won't guarantee you a lesser RMSE simply because the RMSE is computed on the test data which the model has not seen yet. In fact NO metric defined on the training data will **guarantee** you a lesser RMSE on the test data! But with a higher adjusted $R^2$ chances are higher that your RMSE will be lower in the testing data.

To summarise, most likely either the 2nd variable is adding nothing but additional noise in your data or it overfits the model.

Answer (score -1):

R$^2$ will increase with better fit of training data while at the same time generalization error (RMSE on test set) can also increase. This happens when you overfit the model.

Comment: Some stats champion just down voted this. May I know why?

Comment: I just came across this thread.  I confess I needed to read your answer several times and compare it several more times to the question before I appreciated that it goes to the point and it's correct--but I have to use some imagination to understand what you really mean by "better fit of training data." Perhaps the downvote was intended to indicate that more explanation and justification would be useful.  That would explain why a second answer was posted after yours.  It seems to say the same thing but offers more elaboration of the ideas.